# What is the theory behind an askpass on Mac?

Tags: java, bash, macos, shell, terminal

I am making a java program that turns on and off the mysql server through the daemon, the thing is that as many of you know using netbeans does not provide a askpass so whenever the password is asked the program stops, is there an easy way for creating the askpass? I've been watching commands on console the whole day but I still don't know much about console I don't know if mac provides something that can be called quickly or if a gui alert can be designed (javafx)

Comment: What does the Netbeans IDE have to do with the question?

Comment: could this topic help you http://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line ?